# Console animations

Tags: python, python-2.x, console, animation

I'm a coder who's relatively new to *Python* and I wanted to spice up my console applications a bit by making animations. The code I've written works perfectly, but I just wanted to know if it was good in a *pythonic way* and if it follows the *OO* standards. If not please tell me what could be improved and why.

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

class Animation(object): 

    def __init__(self):

        self.frames = []


    def add_frame(self,frame):
        #Adds frame to end of list
        self.frames.append(frame)

    def remove_last_frame(self):
        #Removes last frame in list
        del self.frames[-1]

    def clear_frames(self):
        #Deletes all frames
        del self.frames[:]

    def get_frames(self):
        #Returns list of frames
        return self.frames

    def run_animation(self,loops,fps):
        #Runs the animation at a desired framerate and loops it a given amount of times
        delay = 1.0/fps
        for x in range(0,loops):
            for frame in self.frames:
                #The following line clears the shell
                tmp = sp.call('clear',shell=True)
                print frame
                time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Okay, I changed the title, thanks for your feedback guys

Answer (score 2):

#### Reconsider the need for a class

The functions:

```
def add_frame(self,frame):
    #Adds frame to end of list
    self.frames.append(frame)

def remove_last_frame(self):
    #Removes last frame in list
    del self.frames[-1]

def clear_frames(self):
    #Deletes all frames
    del self.frames[:]

def get_frames(self):
    #Returns list of frames
    return self.frames
```

Are useless and may be removed.

So you are left with a class that has only `__init__` and one other method.

You do not need a class for this:

```
def run_animation(frames, loops, fps):
    delay = 1.0 / fps
    for _ in range(loops):
        for frame in frames:
            sp.call('clear',shell=True)
            print(frame)
            time.sleep(delay)
```

Please do not make a class for the sake of making a class, often it just complicates the code.

---

Minor clean-ups:

- `x` -> `_` as you do not use it.
- `tmp =` -> `` as, again, you do not use it.
- `print frame =` -> `print(frame)` for Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: I have made changes to the __init__ after posting this, now it imports the  animation from a file when it's initialized. Do you still think a class is useless? Because it really cleans up my code

Comment: @SemAllush an empty `__init__` was useless, importing from a file it probably makes sense to have, but maybe not, I cannot really say without seeing the code. I suggest waiting a day and then posting the new version reading from a file up for review.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your functions can, and should be removed.
Most of the functions are just helper functions to `self.frames`,
and some of them are already functions!

- `add_frame` *should be removed*, this is as you should use `frames.append` instead.
- `remove_last_frame` can be replaced with `frames.pop()`
- `clear_frames` is *bad*.

  You used the most performance inefficient approach to do this. Instead just change it's value.

  ```
  >>> import timeit
  >>> timeit.timeit('a=[1,2];del a[:]')
  0.40249805013166945
  >>> timeit.timeit('a=[1,2];a[:] = []')
  0.31216538638113
  >>> timeit.timeit('a=[1,2];a = []')
  0.19833872924905194
  ```
- `get_frames` is un-Pythonic, you don't use getters and setters in Python.
  And if you do, you have sugar to remove the `get_my_var_name`, `set_my_var_name`.

  Also you don't use it yourself...

---

There are a too few spaces in your code, e.g. `1.0 / fps` instead of `1.0/fps`.
But that's not *that* major a problem.
If you want to know more you can read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

One thing that you should change is `range(0,loops)` to `range(loops)`.
It behaves the same and saves you some typing.
Also in Python2 you would want to use `xrange` over `range` for minimal speed benefits, which can add up.
Or leave it as `range` and convert to Python3.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, I just don't understand the timeit bit you wrote? How should that replace what I currently have?

Comment: @SemAllush `timeit` is a way to find how long functions take to run. What it shows is `def clear_frames(self):self.frames = []` would be faster than `def clear_frames(self):del self.frames[:]`. Also someone else may come along with a better review than me, and so you _may_ want to unaccepted my answer and see if you get a better review.